# Display results for 2 different child tables from same parent table

Tags: mysql, sql-server

1. 2 child tables: Driver & Commuter
2. Parent table: User
3. My code and result and expected output(in link):

   select  Booking_ID, Book_Time, u.Name as Driver, u.Name as Commuter from Booking_t book, user_t u
   where  book.Commuter = u.Phone_Num and  extract(month from Book_time) = 2       and extract(year from Book_time) = 2014 and extract(day
   from Book_time) < 16   group by Booking_ID;

[image]

4. `Driver` & `commuter` have `Phone_Num` that is foreign key & referenced to user table `Phone_Num`
5. My code results show the commuter names in both driver & commuter columns but actual output should display drivers names and commuters names in driver and commuter column respectively.
6. When i add `book.Driver = u.Phone_Num` in the where clause to my code mentioned above, the output shows no data.
7. Table structure of `User`, `Driver`, `Commuter` & `booking` (Ignore the other tables in link)
   [image]

Answer (score 0):

> select Booking_ID, Book_Time, **u.Name** as Driver, **u.Name** as Commuter from Booking_t book, user_t u where book.Commuter = u.Phone_Num and extract(month from Book_time) = 2 and extract(year from Book_time) = 2014 and extract(day from Book_time) < 16 group by Booking_ID ;

You are selectin u.Name as both Driver and Commuter. Probably all you need to fix is that one of those should be book.Name.

Comment: Hi @Erik, i don't understand of your book.name as shown in the logical db design there is no Name attribute for Booking table, resulting into unknown column in Booking table.

Comment: Hi @Erik i understand what you are trying to say, i use different names for Driver & Commuter eg a.Name as Driver & b.Name as Commuter but my results show all records except the NULL records for drivers' names who did not bid for the booking. Any possible reason for this?